# Get specific keys and values in the response cycle

Tags: mongodb, express, web, mongoose, backend

```
// const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const Post = require("../models/post");
// const   User= require("../models/user")

module.exports.home= async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.cookies)
        const posts = await Post.find({})
        .populate("users")
        .populate({
            path:'comments',
            populate:{
                path:'user',
            }
        })
        .exec();
        // console.log(posts.content);
        // console.log(posts);

        //    res.cookie("user_id", 25);
        return res.render('home', {
        title: "Home Page ",
        posts:posts,
    }) 

    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("error in sending feed", err);
        return res.redirect("back");

    }
}
```

In the response i am getting the name , email , body and password of the person who made the comment but i want only the name to come in the in the response  how can i fix that

Source code link :- https://github.com/himanshugupta2168/Codeial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `select` option to only pick the properties you want. Update like so:

```
const posts = await Post.find({})
        .populate("users")
        .populate({
            path:'comments',
            populate:{
                path:'user',
                select: 'name -_id'
            }
        })
```

Note that the `_id` is always returned so you can explicitly deselect it with `-_id`. See [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths) for further reading.

Comment: Thank you very much . As a beginner  your answer is indeed of great help to me .

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your learning and the code in your github repo looks pretty good.